# grunt-sass and grunt-contrib-watch seems to not work together as expected

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

I use grunt-sass and grunt-watch to compile and minify my code

```
grunt.config('watch', {
    scripts: {
      files: ['<%= project.src.js.directory %>/*.js'],
      tasks: ['concat:scripts', 'uglify:compile']
    },
    styles: {
      files: [
        '<%= project.src.css.directory %>/**/*.scss'
      ],
      tasks: ['sass:compile', 'cssmin:minify']
    }
});
```

**Problem:**

When I modify one scss file, the `sass:compile` kicks in, `grunt-contrib-watch` detects changes on all javascript files and never run the `cssmin:minify`.

However, running my task (without watch) works well.

I thought `grunt-contrib-watch` was the cause (using spawn to false like instructed in https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-watch/pull/509 kind of fix the issue).

**Does anyone have encountered the same issue?**

Switching to `grunt-contrib-sass` (using ruby-sass) fixes the problem.

---

My Gruntfile.js:

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(grunt) {

  /*
   * Time grunt tasks execution time.
   */
  require('time-grunt')(grunt);

  /*
   * Autoload grunt npm load tasks.
   */
  require('load-grunt-tasks')(grunt);

  /*
   * ==========================================================================
   *  PROJECT
   * ==========================================================================
   */

  var project = {
    'bower': grunt.file.readJSON('./.bowerrc') || { 'directory': './bower_components/' },
    'src': {
      'css' : {
        'directory': 'assets/css',
        'files': [
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/jquery-ui/themes/smoothness/jquery.ui.theme.css',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css',
        ]
      },
      'js': {
        'directory': 'assets/js',
        'files': [
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/jsgettext/lib/Gettext.js',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/jquery-ui/ui/minified/jquery-ui.min.js',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/matchHeight/jquery.matchHeight-min.js',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/twig.js/twig.min.js',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/slick-carousel/slick/slick.min.js',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/jquery-validation/dist/jquery.validate.min.js',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/dropzone/dist/min/dropzone.min.js',
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>/bootstrap-sass/assets/javascripts/bootstrap.min.js',
          '<%= project.src.js.directory %>/main.js',
          '<%= project.src.js.directory %>/messenger.js',
          '<%= project.src.js.directory %>/item.uploader.js',
        ]
      }
    },
    'dest': {
      'css': { 'directory': 'assets/css/dist', },
      'js': { 'directory': 'assets/js/dist', }
    }
  };

  /*
   * ==========================================================================
   *  INIT
   * ==========================================================================
   */

  grunt.initConfig({

    // Load package.json
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

  });

  /*
   * Project configuration.
   *
   * It is set in an early setter to avoid array flattening.
   */
  grunt.config.set('project', project);

  /*
   * ==========================================================================
   *  CONFIGURATION
   * ==========================================================================
   */

  /*
   * sass:compile
   * Compile SASS files to dist directory.
   */
  grunt.config('sass', {
    compile: {
      options: {
        includePaths: [
          '<%= project.bower.directory %>'
        ],
        sourceMap: true,
        style: 'compressed',
      },
      files: {
        "<%= project.dest.css.directory %>/theme1.css": "<%= project.src.css.directory %>/theme1.scss",
        "<%= project.dest.css.directory %>/theme2.css": "<%= project.src.css.directory %>/theme2.scss",
      }
    }
  });

  /*
   * cssmin:minify
   *
   * Concat and minify CSS files.
   *
   * It also rebase url() correctly like relativePath does in LESS.
   */
  grunt.config('cssmin', {
    minify: {
      options: {
        rebase: true
      },
      files: {
        '<%= project.dest.css.directory %>/theme1.min.css': grunt.config('project.src.css.files').concat(['<%= project.dest.css.directory %>/theme1.css']),
        '<%= project.dest.css.directory %>/theme2.min.css': grunt.config('project.src.css.files').concat(['<%= project.dest.css.directory %>/theme2.css'])
      }
    }
  });

  /*
   * concat:scripts
   *
   * Concat Javascript files to a single one (non-minified).
   */
  grunt.config('concat', {
    scripts: {
      options: {
        separator: ';'
      },
      src: grunt.config('project.src.js.files'),
      dest: '<%= project.dest.js.directory %>/main.js'
    }
  });

  /*
   * uglify
   *
   *
   */
  grunt.config('uglify', {
    compile: {
      options: {
        compress: true,
        mangle: true,
        preserveComments: 'some',
        drop_console: true,
      },
      src: '<%= concat.scripts.dest %>',
      dest: '<%= project.dest.js.directory %>/main.min.js'
    }
  });

  /*
   * watch
   *
   * Watch
   */
  grunt.config('watch', {
    options: {
      // interrupt: true, // Cancel build if another changes is detected.
      // reload: true // Reload Grunt if Gruntfiles.js is changed.
    },
    scripts: {
      files: ['<%= project.src.js.directory %>/*.js', /*'Gruntfile.js'*/],
      tasks: ['build:scripts']
    },
    styles: {
      files: [
        '<%= project.src.css.directory %>/**/*.scss',
        '<%= project.bower.directory %>/cssr/src/**/*.scss'
      ],
      tasks: ['build:styles']
    }
  });

  /*
   * ==========================================================================
   *  TASKS
   * ==========================================================================
   */

  grunt.registerTask(
    'build:styles',
    'Compile SASS and minify CSS to dist directory',
    ['sass:compile', 'cssmin:minify']
  );

  grunt.registerTask(
    'build:scripts',
    'Concat scripts files and uglify to dist directory',
    ['concat:scripts', 'uglify:compile']
  );

  grunt.registerTask(
    'build',
    'Build scripts and styles (default task)',
    ['build:styles', 'build:scripts']
  );
  grunt.registerTask(
    'dev',
    'Deprecated, use `grunt build` instead',
    ['build']
  ); // @deprecated

  grunt.registerTask('default', ['watch']);
};
```

For information, my package.json looks like this:

```
{
  ...
  "devDependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
    "time-grunt": "~1.3.0",
    "load-grunt-tasks": "~3.5.0",
    "grunt-contrib-concat": "~0.5.1",
    "grunt-contrib-uglify": "~0.9.2",
    "grunt-contrib-watch": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-sass": "~1.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~1.0.1"
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include the `sass:compile` and `cssmin:minify` tasks? Or better, can you include your whole Gruntfile.js?

Comment: I added my Gruntfile.js! Thanks a lot.